# UIWebView makes app deadlock when playing videos

Tags: ios, uiwebview, avfoundation, deadlock

Our app has a UIWebView that playing videos one by one with html5  tag. We use source and change src.

Time to time app gets the deadlock. It gets it just on iPad air devices(probably coincidence) and iOS 8.

Main thread stack:
[image: Main Thread]

AVAudioSession thread stack:
[image: AVAudioSession Thread]

I thought that the webview must not lock the main thread despite its content.

I would be thankful for any help on this.